# Can we turn printing a variable into a macro

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I often do this a lot

```
    CLog(@"someNew.Title %@", someNew.Title); //Working
    CLog (@"_currentBusiness.managedObjectContext %@",_currentBusiness.managedObjectContext);
    CLog (@"someNew.managedObjectContext %@",someNew.managedObjectContext);
    CLog (@"[ThreadClass managedObjectContext] %@",[ThreadClass managedObjectContext]);
    CLog (@"UIAppDelegate.managedObjectContext %@",UIAppDelegate.managedObjectContext);
```

Basically I do

```
CLog (@"VariableName %@", VariableName)
```

Is there a way to turn this into a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - define the macro like this:

```
#define CLOG(x) CLog(@#x " %@", x)
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
CLOG(someNew.Title);
```

Comment: Don't you think you need a @"#x instead of @#x or does #x turn into "someNew.Title" instead?

Comment: Did you *try* it ? Note that `#` is the preprocessor *stringification* operator.

Comment: It works perfectly. Though I have no idea how. Well, good job still and +1